# Map column names of sql table with an object property, C#, LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I'd appreciate any help.

I wonder if there is a way to map column names of a table with property values of an object.

Sql server table (say, `DATA`) with data:

```
------------------------------------
 NO | NAME        | ADDRESS      
------------------------------------
1    Some name      Some address
2    Another name   Another address
-------------------------------------
```

And another table (say, `FORMATS`) that has static fields:

```
-----------------
ID | LINE_KEY
-----------------
1   NO
2   NAME
3   ADDRESS
```

Now I need to Map the two tables and fill dictionary:

```
DATA someData = db.DATA.Find(2); //get some a record from DATA table

Dictionary<string,string> mappedData = new Dictionary<string,string>();

foreach(FORMAT format in db.FORMATS)
{
   string key = format.LINE_KEY;
   //how??  pseudo code
   string value = someData.Columns(column=>column.NAME == format.LINE_KEY).ColumnValue 
   mappedData.Add(key,value);
}
```

As a result I should have these values in my dictionary:

```
key    | value
----------------------
NO       2
NAME     Another name 
ADDRESS  Another address
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Reflection

```
string value = someData.GetType().GetProperty(key).GetValue(someData).ToString();
```